# Why does it show in the unknown hardware list?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04

I installed nvidia driver with the following tutorial https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-linux.

The installation was successful but when I type `ubuntu-drivers devices` into the terminal again, it still lists:

[image]

The hardware. Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is normal.**

The command

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

shows both the available drivers. Run:

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

or

```
sudo lshw -c video | grep conf
```

that will show the driver in use.

Comment: The question is, when driver was successfully installed, why the hardware still appears?

Comment: Well `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` shows the hardware. I checked on my 18.04.

$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000A65sv00001043sd0000853Bbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GT218 [GeForce 210]
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

Comment: It is normal that it lists the hardware right?

Comment: Yes, it is normal.